# Filter & Convert an Array into String using PHP

Tags: php

How can I turn this array:

print_r($arr)

```
Array (
    [131] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 131
            [vid] => 9
            [name] => apple
            [description] => 
            [weight] => 0
        )

    [112] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 112
            [vid] => 9
            [name] => cool
            [description] => 
            [weight] => 0
        )

    [113] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 113
            [vid] => 9
            [name] => wonderful
            [description] => 
            [weight] => 0
        )

)
```

into this:

**apple cool wonderful**

Basically take out the "name" variable of the array and implode it in order.
I tried implode, but I don't know how to only reference to the "name" variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$terms = array();
foreach($arr as $term) { $terms[] = $term->name; }
print implode($terms, ', ');
```

Comment: I got this error Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings. I'm using drupal.

Comment: Sounds like there's an existing `$terms` variable. Change `$terms` to a different variable name, or do `$terms = array();` before this code.

Comment: The array() think helps pass the error, but I get a blank result. I think this statement is referencing to $arr->name, when it should reference to $arr->anynumber['name']

Comment: Nope. `foreach` steps through each item in `$arr` and turns it into `$term`, so `$term->name` is the correct notation. Try `print_r` ing `$term` to check.

Comment: print_r ing $term gave me the same results as $arr. print_r ing $terms gave me Array ( [0] => )

Comment: I found  a mistake on my side... so after fixing it, print_r ing $term is giving me the object 113. and the following code: foreach($arr as $term) { $terms = array($term->name); }
print implode($terms, ', '); gives me "wonderful"

Comment: You're doing the array() wrong. It needs to be done once, before the `foreach` loop, or you're wiping it out each time `foreach` runs. See my update to the answer.

Comment: You rock! It worked. Thanks for sticking with me the whole hour:)

Answer (score 2):

```
echo join(" ", array_map(create_function('$x', 'return $x->name;'), $arr));
```

Is one way of doing it

Comment: for some reason I can't get this to work... I'm trying to figure it out

Comment: it doesn't work, because the "name" is under a number. $arr->##["name"]. And that number can be any number, like $arr->131["name"], $arr->113["name"]... you cannot refrence to it like $arr->name or $arr["name"]

Comment: That's the whole point of `array_map` - it's turning each term into `$x` for easier access. Please check the documentation on these functions before dismissing them.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is - I'm trying to get past the "object", number 131, 112, 113, etc... and pull out the name from the object. I'm probably not making sense because of my lack of vocabulary... basically the arrays are stored under the objects, and I need to pull the "name" variable in the array, while I don't know that object name (object 131, 112, 113, etc...)

Comment: I found an error on my side, after fixing it, I'm getting the following error:
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in filename.php